# How can I populate the details of all the products related to opportunity

Tags: apex

I have to render VF page as PDF. It should display opportunity fields and a table showing related opportunity product details in PDF form.I am gettin a table for opportunity but am not able to populate the details of all the products related to opportunity which Shows product details in a table populating following opportunity product fields,
a)  Date
b)  Discount
c)  List Price
d)  Product Code
e)  Quantity
f)  Sales Price
g)  Subtotal
h)  Total Price
Can anyone help me out with this.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity" renderAs="pdf">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunity.opportunityLineitems}" var="product">
            <apex:column value="{!product.Name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You need to use `{!opportunity.opportunityLineitems}`

Comment: Thanq..this helped alot.. But now the problem is I want the opportunity fields like  Opportunity Name,Parent Account Name,Stage,Type... together with product fields

Comment: use like above `{!opportunity.name}`, `{!opportunity.stage}` and `{!opportunity.Type}` with my code

Comment: ya perfectly workin.. but am not able to get the date field of product.. Otherwise all the other fields are coming

Comment: close date? `{!opportunity.CloseDate}`, check date field having value or not also accessible or not?

Comment: if is it `{!product.ServiceDate}`  then check it is null or not

Comment: ya thanx a ton..everthingz perfect nw..